# Running multiple flask applications with different domain names using mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi, flask

We are trying to run 2 different flask applications with different domain names from same server using mod_wsgi + Apache2.

This is the settings configured in httpd.conf

```
# For www.yyy.com
WSGIDaemonProcess yyy python-path=/var/www/yyy
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/yy/wsgi.py process-group=yyy application-group=%{GLOBAL}

# For www.zzz.com
WSGIDaemonProcess zzz python-path=/var/www/zzz
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/zzz/wsgi.py process-group=zzz application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

and created /etc/httpd/conf.d/yyy.conf & zzz.conf similar to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.yyy.com
        ServerAdmin joel
        DocumentRoot /var/www/yyy
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined
        Alias /static /var/www/yyy/static
        <Directory /var/www/yyy/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/yyy>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but whatever we try we end up getting only first application that is configured in httpd.conf.

Comment: Can you share both apache config files? Also, how are you enabling them, are they in sites-available?

Answer (score 1):

My query was answered by Graham Dumpleton, mod_wsgi mailing list. He asked me to remove all mod_wsgi settings from httpd.conf and move them in virtualhost config file /etc/httpd/conf.d/yyy.conf and zzz.conf as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.yyy.com
        ServerAdmin joel
        DocumentRoot /var/www/yyy
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined
        WSGIDaemonProcess yyy python-path=/var/www/yyy
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/yy/wsgi.py process-group=yyy application-group=%{GLOBAL}
        Alias /static /var/www/yyy/static
        <Directory /var/www/yyy/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/yyy>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```